# m2eclipse plug-in as a local site repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

is it possible to download the m2eclipse plug-in so that I can install it from eclipse as a local site?
if so, can you point me to the link, I could not find it on the m2eclipse site here:

[m2e eclipse download link](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/)

====================================

Tried @Torsten's comments

I created a batch file with this entry:

```
@echo off
set ECLIPSE=D:/DevProgs/dumps/Eclipse3.5
echo Mirroring metadata for %1
java -jar %ECLIPSE%/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar \
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication \
 -source %1 \
 -destination p2-mirror \
 -destinationName "D:\temp" \
 -verbose \
 -compare
```

and called the batch file, but it simply starts eclipse and nothing happens... can you tell me what to do after this?

```
D:\DevAreas\test>DownloadEclipseRepo.bat "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/"
Mirroring metadata for "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/"
```

and the batch file does not do anything else.

When I stop the batch file.. it complains something like this:

```
D:\DevAreas\test>DownloadEclipseRepo.bat "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/"
Mirroring metadata for "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/"
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C'-application' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-destination' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-destinationName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-verbose' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-compare' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
D:\DevAreas\test>
```

Could you please provide some more clarity/suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that the command is not recognized to be a "multi-line" command. Try one-lining it by removing the "/", fx: "java -jar %ECLIPSE%/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source %1 -destination p2-mirror -destinationName "D:\temp" -verbose -compare"

Answer (score 2):

Sadly enough more and more Eclipse projects are no longer distributed as Zips or downloadable sites. This really hurts people building offline installations.

Modern times ...

I think this is the case with M2Eclipse as well. As a solution you can use a p2.mirror script to retrieve a local copy of the site from the p2 repository like the one below, which is using a local Eclipse 3.5 installation. You may want to adapt thi to what you have at hand.

Hope this helps,

Torsten

```
#!/bin/sh
ECLIPSE=C:/eclipse3.5

echo Mirroring metadata for $1
java -jar ${ECLIPSE}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar \
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication \
 -source ${1} \
 -destination p2-mirror \
 -destinationName "Corporate P2 Repo" \
 -verbose \
 -compare

echo Mirroring artifacts for $1
java -jar ${ECLIPSE}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar \
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication \
 -source ${1} \
 -destination p2-mirror \
 -destinationName "Corporate P2 Repo" \
 -verbose \
 -compare
```

Comment: thank you, the second part of the code snippet is repeated. Is this intentional? Also, will it create a copy of the remote repository specified by variable ${1} onto the location "Corporate P2 Repo" something like C:\my_local_repo.. is it so?

Comment: I created a batch file with this entry: 
@echo off
set ECLIPSE=D:/DevProgs/dumps/Eclipse3.5

echo Mirroring metadata for %1
java -jar %ECLIPSE%/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar \
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication \
 -source %1 \
 -destination p2-mirror \
 -destinationName "D:\temp" \
 -verbose \
 -compare

Comment: please see my edited comments in the question... Can you suggest what needs to be done?

Comment: The script will create a copy of the remote repository specified by variable ${1} onto the location "Corporate P2 Repo" something like <cwd>/p2-mirror. You might want to create another argument for the destination location, the duplicate invocation is intentional. You find a windows batch version here, where the above version is based upon: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?79601-Setting-up-a-local-mirror-site